# how to identify first transaction in java

Tags: java

Let's consider the operation of list update, where I can add and remove the member and on every addition or removal of member, we wish to notify to list owner except 1st addition.  e.g when I add the first member, notification will not be send, but when, next member is added or existing member is removed then notification should be send. in-short, how to identify first transaction in java? or how to implement this using Java?

Comment: read this (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add boolean variable `shouldNotify` that would be initially set to `false`. Then, in methods, that `add` and `remove` elements you should check for this variable and if it true - notify users. If not - just set it to true.

```
if(shouldNotify) {
    sendNotification();
} else {
    shouldNotify = true;
}
```